# Helm prevent from adding the default chart repo on helm init

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, openshift, kubernetes-helm

I want to use Helm with Gitlab to deploy my services to OpenShift.

I have a Gitlab Runner deployed in OpenShift.

I already have Tiller installed in Openshift under the `tiller` namespace and am using the docker image `docker.greater.com.au/platform/images/dtzar/helm-kubectl:latest`

My system is also behind a proxy which I won't be able to get past.

As part of one of my Gitlab CI build steps I have the following:

```
$ helm init --client-only
Creating /root/.helm 
Creating /root/.helm/repository 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/cache 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/local 
Creating /root/.helm/plugins 
Creating /root/.helm/starters 
Creating /root/.helm/cache/archive 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml 
Adding stable repo with URL: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com 
Error: Looks like "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Get https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/index.yaml: Proxy Authorization Required
```

My main question is I am wondering if it's possible to disable Helm from trying to add `https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com` as a repostiory as part of `helm init`?

It might be worth noting that I do not know if helm init --client-only is a required step in using helm with this setup.

I have also tried a simple `helm version` and the server is responding with a Proxy Authorization Required error.

```
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.12.1", 
GitCommit:"02a47c7249b1fc6d8fd3b94e6b4babf9d818144e", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: Get https://---.---.---.---:---/api/v1/namespaces/tiller/pods?labelSelector=app%3Dhelm%2Cname%3Dtiller: Proxy Authorization Required
```

I've removed the IP address but it's trying to resolve the Tiller server from the wrong IP address when running this `helm version` command.

Comment: Did you download the binary from github pages? or, did you compiled it in pc from scratch?

Comment: Also what is your version? and, OS?

Comment: Good questions. I believe I downloaded the binaries from Github. The version for helm is
`Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.12.0", GitCommit:"d325d2a9c179b33af1a024cdb5a4472b6288016a", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.12.0", GitCommit:"d325d2a9c179b33af1a024cdb5a4472b6288016a", GitTreeState:"clean"}`
OS is Windows Server 2012 for Openshift.
Apologies if I haven't answered your questions correctly, I'm quite new to containers and container management etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define which stable repository you would like to use with option `-o --stable-repo-url url`.

Example: `helm init --client-only --stable-repo-url https://path.to.my.repo`

You could found more info [here](https://docs.helm.sh/helm/#helm-init)

Comment: In my setup, there is no Tiller, but I rather use helm for generating Kubernetes resources that are later installed with `kubectl`. On a fresh helm installation, I have been having an error as in the question. Your answer did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: but if my --stable-repo-url is a private one, how to append the command with user and password?

Comment: but if my --stable-repo-url is a private one, how to append the command with user and password?

Comment: @LeiYang have you tried to use basic http auth like  `--stable-repo-url https://user:pass@path.to.my.repo` ?